# Touch Screen Not responding but stylus works

Tags: touchscreen

This is a little different to other posts. I have a **Samsung Note 20 Ultra**

- There is no damage to the phone or screen
- I have not dropped it
- Suddenly in the middle of browsing the touchscreen stopped responding
- Since I have fingerprint access, its hard to do anything
- I used the stylus to boot into safe mode
- The issue is still there
- I have checked all touch screen settings

  - Accidental Touch Protection is off
  - Touch Sensitivity - tried on and off
  - Touch and Hold delay is 0.5 sec
  - Tap duration is off
  - Ignore repeated touches is off
- I tried *#2663# to recalibrate touchscreen, the firmware update fails.

Is this an Android issue or is it hardware ?

Comment: Hardware issue. Backup  your data while you can to cloud, PC wherever//If you still suspect Android do a factory-reset after backing up and I am pretty sure your problem will remain//S-pen is independent of touch screen function. I can't back this statement with evidence but that's the case AFAIK

Comment: I have come to that inclusion. I think that either the connector has fallen off the top layer of the screen OR the digitizer has gone.  The seller will fix under warranty.  But its a pain I have bank authenticator apps that are meant to he installed from the appropriate countries. It was a mission to do it. I had to use Google account for that country together with a VPN.

Comment: The seller failed to fix the phone after 5 weeks, and voluntarily gave me a brand-new one.